# Is load testing is possible on iPhone app?

Tags: ios, iphone, load-testing

I want to test the reaction of app when 1000 user hit on my app. So is load testing is possible on iPhone app?

Comment: you can do load testing with postman .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36307005/load-testing-with-postman-rest-restful-tool

Comment: You don't load test an **app**, you wouldn't have 1000 users using one device, you load test your API, so this question is not really related to ios/iphone tags

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to test your servers when 1000 users, each with an iPhone, use your app at the same time? If yes, then that would be too broad a question to ask here. Please read the [help] pages on what questions can be asked here and on how to write a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Vaibhav let me summarize the load testing, for applications I always load test their Api, you can't load test a mobile application.
But if you still want to check mobile application with certain number of clicks, I automate the mobile application and mark a locator to be clicked multiple times for a single request, you can manage rampup time with "click and wait" but not exactly like the api testing, you can also maually give time after each click. This is the closest I have go to test a mobile application for load. 
If you need further help hit me up in the comments and I will share my method wih screenshots.